# What's the right way to save a record and keep the Primary Key using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-insert

I am attempting to seed data into a newly created database in Entity Framework 6. (Or replace it on the fly) This is for dev/testing purposes and possibly for future production installs. I have several XML files that were exported from production environments that I need to get into the dev and test environments. To do this right, I need to keep the primary keys on the lookup tables. The code below shows how I finally got something working. I spent a day searching for the "right way" to do it and sadly ended up hard coding a query string as the code shows.

```
public void Add(QuestionType questionType)
{
  using (var context = new SurveyFromDBContext())
  {
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
      try
      {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Kiosk].[QuestionTypes] ON");
        string sql = "INSERT INTO [KIOSK].[QuestionTypes] ( [Id], [Name], [Description]) VALUES (" +
          questionType.Id + ", '" + questionType.Name + "', '" + questionType.Description + "')";
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

        //context.QuestionTypes.Add(questionType);

        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Kiosk].[QuestionTypes] OFF");
        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The question is: Within EF6 how is one supposed to insert records into a table and keep the primary key?

Note that the primary key needs to be able to auto-update because of legacy code so I can't do this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Unless that can somehow be done on the fly.

Comment: are you asking how to insert your own values into a normally auto-generated field?

Comment: have you attempted to turn the query as is, into a stored procedure?  at least then you'd be able to protect yourself against SQL injection.  Outside of that, my only other thought would be to turn off the identity on the database table (though doing so might cause unforseen consequences)

Comment: Claies: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: user2366842: I'd like to say that I can't go the stored procedure way but I can at least say I don't want to. I'm trying to figure out how to get Entity Framework to do the insert but keep the PK value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any good way to do this.  What you are doing strikes me as more of an ETL-related task than an ORM task.

One improvement over what you have is this (tested; works in combination with DatabaseGeneratedOption you described above).  I don't believe there's a need to turn identity_insert back off; it reverts to off after the update anyway:

```
        using ( var context = new YourEntities() )
        {
            var connection = (SqlConnection)context.Database.Connection;
            using ( var cmd = new SqlCommand( "set identity_insert QuestionTypes on", connection) )
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            var qt = new QuestionType { id = 2, name = "test" };
            context.QuestionTypes.Add( qt);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: You are likely correct dudeNumber4 in thinking that this is ETL work. I don't have the DB people around to do that work for me so I'm trying to do it via code. (We've got DB environment issues at work right now so I'm trying to make this process agnostic. For the past couple of months I've had to use a local DB or SQL Server 2008r2 on a desktop box because there hasn't been a dev or test environment.)

I'm also trying to get things setup so that people can manually modify files to create the setup for test scenarios.

Comment: dudeNumber4: when I comment out the line that does the insert and use the currently commented out line "context.QuestionTypes.Add(questionType);" then Entity Framework takes over and lets the database generate its own ID. My research shows the reason for that is because the .Add in EF is wrapped in its own transaction and the work I've done creating one around that gets ignored.

Comment: @user1582732: Marking the column in the model as DatabaseGeneratedOption.None simply tells the model what to expect out of the database.  When the query is submitted to the database, then it simply does what it will always do no matter where you submit the query from.  The snippet above is using EF *as if* the id wasn't identity, but no, it'll never work without the identity_insert command.